# Testing FPS using Android plugin for Eclipse?

Tags: android

Ive no doubt this question may have been addressed before but how can I turn on a framerate monitor to use when I run my programs using the android emulator so I can see exactly what my android game is achieving at a given time?

Comment: You need to calculate by hand. Check [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/52bb5927f8f5cac3).

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRefreshRate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRefreshRate%28%29)

```
 windowManager = (WindowManager) applicationContext.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
 display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
 display.getRefreshRate();
```